# OpenCV's Canny Edge Detection in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, edge-detection

I want to extract the edges of hand but I get the following result. I've tried adjusting the low and high threshold but I still can't get the desired output. I have included below the code and its output. What seems to be the problem?

This is the [output image](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5273/cannyj.jpg) generated by the code below.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main(){

    cv::Mat image= cv::imread("open_1a.jpg");
    cv::Mat contours;
    cv::Mat gray_image;

    cvtColor( image, gray_image, CV_RGB2GRAY );

    cv::Canny(image,contours,10,350);

    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image",image);

    cv::namedWindow("Gray");
    cv::imshow("Gray",gray_image);

    cv::namedWindow("Canny");
    cv::imshow("Canny",contours);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change this line

```
cvtColor( image, gray_image, CV_RGB2GRAY );
```

to

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::Mat hsv;
cv::cvtColor( image, hsv, CV_RGB2HSV );
cv::split(hsv, channels);
gray_image = channels[0];
```

The problem seems to be that your hand in gray scale is very close to the gray background. I have applied Canny on the hue (color) because the skin color should be sufficiently different.

Also, the Canny thresholds look a bit crazy. The accepted norm is that the higher one should be 2x to 3x the lower. 350 is a bit too much and it doesn't help solve the main problem.

**Edit**

with these thresholds I was able to extract quite a good contour

cv::Canny(image,contours,35,90);

Reading a bit of theory about the algorithm will help you understand what happens and what you should do to improve. `wiki canny` on google

However, the improvement above will give you much better results (provided you use better thresholds than 10, 350. Try (40, 120) )