# opencv c++ Edge detection to find edge that the top of it is white and the bottom is black

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection

I am a new learner of opencv,now I want to deal some picture like some card,I want to find its edge,I notice that the bottom edge's bottom is black and its top is white,does opencv has a way to find edge like this?

Comment: you should show what efforts you have tried to resolve the problem and what is the result and where you think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can help you find edges using `Canny Edge Detector`
You can refer for the implementation in this link

[OpenCV's Canny Edge Detection in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987483/opencvs-canny-edge-detection-in-c)

Furthermore, I would like you to first do a bit of research on your own before actually asking for questions here.

Comment: Thank you.But the canny will find all edge.I only want to find some special edge which's top is white and its bottom is black.